# Java: Dialog box stuck in loop if input "Y" but not if input "N"

Tags: java

The program asks for a bunch of inputs, then gets to the one where it asks if the user would like to runAnother report. Problem is when the user puts in "Y" it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

If the user puts in "N" then it changes the runAnother variable and exits the loop. I don't understand why its getting stuck in a loop, constantly popping up the "Would you like to run another report" box when I want it to start the do while loop over again from the top. looking for any suggestions or pointers to help me fix this problem.

Thanks.

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class SalesReportArrayConnorS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Declarartions

        int total = 0;
        int numProperties;
        int counter;
        int loopIndex;
        int propertyPrice[];
        int exception;
        String runAnother = "Y";
        String propertyAddress[];
        final String HEADING1 = "MONTH-END SALES REPORT";
        final String HEADING = "Address\t\t\tPrice";

        //First Box

        numProperties = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many properties would you like to enter? "));

        //Output Headers

        System.out.println(HEADING1);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(HEADING);

        //Declare Array

        propertyAddress = new String[numProperties];
        propertyPrice = new int[numProperties];

        //While Loop

        counter = 1; //Makes sure counter on numProperties and prices starts with 1 instead of 0
        loopIndex = 0;

        do{
            while (loopIndex < numProperties){

                //Verifying numProperties is between 1 and 10
                if (numProperties > 10){
                    numProperties = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("**ERROR: Enter a number between 1 and 10. \nHow many properties would you like to enter? "));
                }
                else if (numProperties < 1){
                    numProperties = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("**ERROR: Enter a number between 1 and 10. \nHow many properties would you like to enter? "));
                }

                //Input propertyAddress and price in the arrays
                propertyAddress[loopIndex] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the address for property " + counter + ": ");

                //Attempting to catch a NumberFormatException if a number is not entered
                exception = 1;
                do {
                    try {
                        propertyPrice[loopIndex] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the value of propery " + counter + ": "));
                        exception++;
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                        propertyPrice[loopIndex] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("**ERROR: Please enter a numeric value: "));
                        exception++;
                    } 
                } while (exception == 1);

                //Verifying property price is not 0
                if (propertyPrice[loopIndex] == 0){propertyPrice[loopIndex] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("**ERROR: Enter a number greater than 0. \nEnter the value of property " + counter + ": "));
                }

                //Add one to counters
                counter++;
                loopIndex++;    
            }

            runAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to run another report? ");

        } while (runAnother.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));




        //loop to print out address, price arrays, and calculate total.

        for (loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < numProperties; loopIndex++){
            total += propertyPrice[loopIndex];
            System.out.println(propertyAddress[loopIndex] + "\t\t" + propertyPrice[loopIndex]);

        }

        //Print total
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total\t\t\t" + total);

        //Exit System
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `loopIndex` is not reset and therefore the

```
while (loopIndex < numProperties){
```

loop never gets entered into

After (or just before)

```
runAnother = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to run another report? ");
```

set `loopIndex` to `0`

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer, I just realized this.